# Why is Ruby output suppressed on the console?

Tags: ruby

```
# code.rb
def hello
  puts "hello"
end

:$ ruby code.rb
```

Nothing is output on the console! I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

If I run the same code in IRB it works!

Comment: What does IRB output in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call your code, you're just defining a method:

```
    # code.rb
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end

    hello

$ ruby code.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method, in this case, `hello` in the script:

```
def hello
  puts "hello"
end

hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You define a method, but you're never calling it.  Try this:

```
# code.rb
def hello
  puts "hello"
end

hello
```

Run it:

```
:$ ruby code.rb
```